# I am getting Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)?

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception

I am developing WorldNews Android App using Bottom Navigation Drawer, however, I am getting the following exception below.

```
Process: yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.worldnews, PID: 4478
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.worldnews/yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.worldnews.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)' on a null object reference
        at me.riddhimanadib.library.BottomNavigationBar.<init>(BottomNavigationBar.java:65)
        at me.riddhimanadib.library.BottomBarHolderActivity.setupBottomBarHolderActivity(BottomBarHolderActivity.java:36)
        at yodgobekkomilov.edgar.com.worldnews.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
2018-10-01 19:31:35.214 1393-1440/? E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (4 threads) starved for 203 ms
2018-10-01 19:31:35.215 1575-1588/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-10-01 19:31:35.519 1393-1440/? E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (4 threads) starved for 105 ms
2018-10-01 19:31:35.712 1575-1592/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2018-10-01 19:31:35.812 1450-1450/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2018-10-01 19:31:35.812 1450-1450/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2018-10-01 19:31:35.814 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2018-10-01 19:31:35.827 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2018-10-01 19:31:35.827 2574-4505/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2018-10-01 19:31:35.828 2574-4505/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-01 19:31:42.172 1450-1536/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2018-10-01 19:31:42.172 1450-1536/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2018-10-01 19:31:42.172 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2018-10-01 19:31:42.188 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2018-10-01 19:31:42.189 2574-4505/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2018-10-01 19:31:42.245 2574-4505/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-01 19:31:42.333 1575-1588/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-10-01 19:31:46.110 1575-1588/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-10-01 19:31:47.638 1450-1536/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2018-10-01 19:31:47.638 1450-1536/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2018-10-01 19:31:47.638 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2018-10-01 19:31:47.672 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2018-10-01 19:31:47.672 2574-4505/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2018-10-01 19:31:47.673 2574-4505/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-01 19:31:48.001 1575-1588/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-10-01 19:31:48.758 1575-1671/? E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
2018-10-01 19:31:52.885 1450-1536/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2018-10-01 19:31:52.885 1450-1536/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2018-10-01 19:31:52.886 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2018-10-01 19:31:52.904 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2018-10-01 19:31:52.904 2574-4505/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2018-10-01 19:31:52.918 2574-4505/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-01 19:31:58.384 1450-1450/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2018-10-01 19:31:58.384 1450-1450/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2018-10-01 19:31:58.395 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2018-10-01 19:31:58.445 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2018-10-01 19:31:58.446 2574-4505/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2018-10-01 19:31:58.449 2574-4505/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-01 19:32:00.006 1575-1588/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-10-01 19:32:03.819 1575-1588/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-10-01 19:32:03.858 1450-1450/? E/AudioFlinger: not enough memory for AudioTrack size=131296
2018-10-01 19:32:03.859 1450-1450/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
2018-10-01 19:32:03.859 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
2018-10-01 19:32:03.866 2574-4505/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.
2018-10-01 19:32:03.866 2574-4505/? E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
2018-10-01 19:32:03.869 2574-4505/? E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
2018-10-01 19:32:04.054 1575-1592/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2018-10-01 19:32:04.073 1575-1588/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2018-10-01 19:32:05.145 2365-2465/? E/AsyncOpDispatcher: Could not get module info from current context.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to get current module info in ModuleManager created with non-module Context
        at com.google.android.chimera.config.ModuleManager.getCurrentModule(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):2)
        at wwj.b(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):1)
        at wwj.<init>(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):8)
        at wwj.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):9)
        at com.google.android.gms.icing.mdd.service.DataDownloadChimeraService.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):14)
        at wwd.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):26)
        at pmz.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):46)
        at pnh.a(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):110)
        at pbi.run(:com.google.android.gms@13280022@13.2.80 (040700-211705629):8)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
```

below My MainActivity.java where I am getting an exception.

```
public class MainActivity extends BottomBarHolderActivity implements AllJazeeraFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, BBCFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, CNNFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, CBCNewsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {


    //    private ApiService apiService;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        NavigationPage page1 = new NavigationPage("AllJazeera", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.alljazeera), AllJazeeraFragment.newInstance());
        NavigationPage page2 = new NavigationPage("Support", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bbc_icon), CNNFragment.newInstance());
        NavigationPage page3 = new NavigationPage("Billing", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cnn_icon), AllJazeeraFragment.newInstance());
        NavigationPage page4 = new NavigationPage("Profile", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cbc_icon), CBCNewsFragment.newInstance());

        List<NavigationPage> navigationPages = new ArrayList<>();
        navigationPages.add(page1);
        navigationPages.add(page2);
        navigationPages.add(page3);
        navigationPages.add(page4);

        super.setupBottomBarHolderActivity(navigationPages);
    }


    public void onClicked() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: The library readme tells you to remove `setContentView()` so I would do that first.

Comment: @TheWanderer I removed setContentView but error still appearing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change build.gradle file, set minifyEnabled to false it will work

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

add below line in proguard-rules.pro file, which will present in \app folder

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

Like this

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
```

Hope this will work...!

Comment: where exactly, I have to add I did not understand sorry